# Quickbooks Online Integration requires caching to be disabled

Tags: security, caching, quickbooks-online

I was looking to integrate with QOB, but git a roadblock when reading their security requirements, the first point states;

*"Caching has been disabled on all SSL pages and all pages that contain sensitive data by using value no-cache and no-store instead of private in the Cache-Control header."*

How does preventing caching help with security. If I stop caching my web pages, the performance will be affected adversely for sure. Before I take such an extreme step I wanted help in understanding if this is a standard requirement or is there a workaround to this.

Tx

Answer (score 0):

If you allow caching, then sensitive data would be cached on the end-users computer.

If the end-users computer happened to be a public computer (e.g. a library computer, or at a university) then that cached data might be available to other (potentially malicious) people who used that same computer later.

Thus, disabling caching may increase security.

Honestly, it's not all that extreme, and is quite common from a PCI-compliance and security-compliance context in general. If you're serious about security, you shouldn't be allowing caching on pages with any sort of sensitive data on them.